# Why does div#navbar and div #navbar have different results?

Tags: html, css

Code is as shown below. Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/tLXSt/ .

```
 <div id="navbar">

<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="fb" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different selectors:

- `div#navbar` selects the `div` with an `id` of `navbar`
- `div #navbar` selects the element with an `id` of `navbar` that is a descendant of a `div` element.

Basically, the first one matches:

```
<div id="navbar">
  Hello
</div>
```

But the second one matches:

```
<div>
  <img src="foo.png" id="navbar" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`div#navbar` looks for a div id'd navbar

`div #navbar` looks for something id'd navbar inside all divs

To explain, best as I can, these things are called CSS selectors. You can specify selectors in different ways; in the first one, you have a bunch of selectors together. This looks for an element that fits that description.

Each time you have a space, it's like "now start looking for elements that are in (are children of) the last selector.

So that's why no space (`div#navbar`) for a div **with** id navbar, and with space (`div #navbar`) looks for an id navbar **in** a div.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used when you have a nested tags or elements. For example.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="base"> <!-- i want to select this for my css instead of... -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="base"> <!-- this -->
</div>
```

I want to select the ID base inside container so I'll use...

```
#container #base {
    // styles
}
```

If you use only...

```
#base {
    //styles
}
```

The base ID outside the container will be called out, too. Logic.

So to understand it more properly. Here's an example

```
#div1 #div2 #div3 .test img {
    height:100px;
}
```

The image inside 'test' class, inside 'div3' ID, inside 'div2' ID, inside 'div1' ID will have a height of 100px.